# How to put an class on specific (first element) inside loop?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

In Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Slide, is needed a class called "active" to set which image is first for all slide and then initialize the cycle. But, how can I set this class if my objects (that I want to show in slide) are in a loop?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide img-polaroid">
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    {% for slide in slides_list %}
    <div class="item"> <!-- Here goes the class="active" -->
      <img src="{{slide.imagem.url}}" alt="{{slide.imagem.titulo}}" />
      <div class="carousel-caption slider">
        <h2>{{slide.titulo}}</h2>
        <p>{{slide.mensagem}}</p>
      </div><!--/carousel-caption-->
    </div><!--/item-->
    {% endfor %}

  </div><!--/carousel-inner-->

  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>

</div><!--/myCarousel-->
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{% for slide in slides_list %}
<div class="item{% if forloop.first %} active{% endif %}">
  <img src="{{slide.imagem.url}}" alt="{{slide.imagem.titulo}}" />
  <div class="carousel-caption slider">
    <h2>{{slide.titulo}}</h2>
    <p>{{slide.mensagem}}</p>
  </div><!--/carousel-caption-->
</div><!--/item-->
{% endfor %}
```

[The `for` tag and the `forloop` variable docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: I just needed to make a small correction: `<div class="item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}">`. Thanks!